# Accents not showing correctly in workbench but ok in php website

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, diacritics

I am using a utf8 mysql database and a utf8 environment with php.
Inserted some texts with accents using php and then selected them through php. The accents are being correctly printed on the screen.
My problem is that they are not showing correctly in workbench and when I manually insert some values, these values are not correctly printed on screen when selected with php.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any chance that you might be able to post your code?

Comment: mysql_query("insert into itens (ite_titulo) values ('téstü') "); through php, and this how I set php environment to utf8: ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8'); header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

Comment: Which version of php are you using?

Comment: You're absolutely certain the table you're inserting into is set to use UTF-8? I ask because this is exactly the behavior I would expect if it was expecting latin1 but being given UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to tell the database connection you're sending it UTF-8 strings from the PHP end:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

If you insert UTF-8 bytes into the database as ISO-8859-1 bytes, and retrieve them in the same way, which is what I suspect you're currently doing, your app will be OK despite them appearing wrong from the database's point of view. What you'll lose by doing it that way is working collation for non-ASCII characters, so case-sensitive comparisons in particular may fail unexpectedly.

Comment: it worked only by adding this piece of code after each connection.